# Bezier curve with mouse event

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mouseevent, bezier

I want to draw a bezier curve with mouse event.

```
function draw(selection)
{
    var keep = false, path, xy0;
    line = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate(function(points) {return points.join("M10 80 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150, 180 80"); })
        .x(function(d) {return d[0];})
        .y(function(d) {return d[1];});

    selection
        .on('mousedown', function() {
            keep = true;
            xy0 = d3.mouse(this);
            path = d3.select('svg')
                .append('path')
                .attr('d', line([xy0, xy0]))
                .style({'stroke': 'black', 'stroke-width': '3px'});
        })
        .on('mouseup', function() {
            keep = false;
        })
        .on('mousemove', function(){
            if(keep) {
                Line = line([xy0, d3.mouse(this).map(function(x) {return x - 1;})]);
                console.log(Line);
                path.attr('points', Line);
            }
        });
}
```

But it doesn't work. Do you have an idea how to do that?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  This line `points.join("M10 80 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150, 180 80");` makes little sense.  On mousemove with button clicked you want to draw a curve between the mousedown position and current position?

Comment: I want to draw a bezier curve between the mousedown position and current position. M10 80 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150, 180 80 is the bezier curve parameter. How can I implement this in my code? Thanks

Comment: "*But it doesn't work*" is not a problem statement, it is an opinion at best (the code is doing exactly what you wrote it to do; it works exactly as the source code intends it to work): what did you **expect** this code to do, what is it doing instead, where do you think that difference is coming from, and *what have you tried so far to fix that*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Still not sure I understand the question.

> M10 80 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150, 180 80 is the bezier curve parameter

No, that's a path's "d" attribute which draws a **specific** bezier curve.  I'm not sure how you'd combine that with your mouse movements.  I tried to and I guess it produces curves of a sort:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.17" data-semver="3.5.17" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var keep = false,
      mouseStart = null,
      controlPoints = "C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150,";

    var svg = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', 500)
      .attr('height', 500)
      .style('border', '1px solid black');

    var path = svg.append("path")
      .style("stroke", "steelblue")
      .style("stroke-width", "2px")
      .style("fill", "none");

    svg.on('mousedown', function() {
        keep = true;
        mouseStart = d3.mouse(this);
      })
      .on('mouseup', function() {
        keep = false;
      })
      .on('mousemove', function() {
        var mouseEnd = d3.mouse(this);
        if (keep) {
          path.attr("d", "M" + mouseStart + controlPoints + mouseEnd);
        }
      });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

If you want a *smooth* curve from start to end you could try something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.17" data-semver="3.5.17" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var keep = false,
      mouseStart = null;

    var svg = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', 500)
      .attr('height', 500)
      .style('border', '1px solid black');

    var path = svg.append("path")
      .style("stroke", "steelblue")
      .style("stroke-width", "2px")
      .style("fill", "none");

    svg.on('mousedown', function() {
        keep = true;
        mouseStart = d3.mouse(this);
      })
      .on('mouseup', function() {
        keep = false;
      })
      .on('mousemove', function() {
        var mouseEnd = d3.mouse(this);
        if (keep) {
          var dx = mouseStart[0] - mouseEnd[0],
            dy = mouseStart[1] - mouseEnd[1],
            dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
          path.attr("d", "M" +
            mouseStart[0] + "," +
            mouseStart[1] + "A" +
            dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " +
            mouseEnd[0] + "," +
            mouseEnd[1]);
        }
      });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```